# Interchanging sum with integral for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I have a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and I have shown that the sum $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+2kT)$$ converges absolutely in the $L^1([-T,T])$ norm, i.e $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}||f(x+2kT)||_{1_{[-T,T]}} < \infty$

I would now like to find a fourier expansion of this sum. I came across the following term:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+2kT) \exp(-inx) \ d\lambda(x)$$
and I would like to pull the sum out of the integral. I was thinking about using dominated convergence by saying that 
$$\left|\sum_{k=-N}^Nf(x+2kT) \exp(-inx)\right| \le \sum_{k=-N}^N|f(x+2kT)|  $$

I am not sure if this is enough because I only know that that sum is integrable over $[-T,T]$.. Is there any way to fix this or can you generally not tell whether or not the above sum can be interchanged with the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-N}^{N}|f(x+2kT)|\leq\sum_{k\in{\bf{Z}}}|f(x+2kT)|$ and $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{k\in{\bf{Z}}}|f(x+2kT)|dx=\sum_{k\in{\bf{Z}}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x+2kT)|dx<\infty$.

Comment: The inequality in the second row holds because of the sigma additivity of the integral, right? But why must the last term be smaller than infinity? What if $T < \pi$ ?

Comment: The equality is due to Monotone Convergence Theorem. By the way, I just wonder why the integral is taken on $[-\pi,\pi]$, or should it be $[0,T]$, the function is periodic with length $T$, because you want to do the fourier transform on that, it depends on the periodicity of the function.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|dx =\lim_{K \to \infty} \int_{-(2K-1)T}^{(2K+1)T} |f(x)|dx=\lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K  \int_{2k-T}^{2k+T} |f(x)|dx$ $= \lim_{K \to \infty} \sum_{k=-K}^K \int_{-T}^{T} |f(x+2kT)|dx < \infty$ is the assumption that $f \in L^1$, we don't need any theorem @Jack4t3

Comment: Just a comment here: the periodicity is $2T$, sorry for miscounting, so the integral should be taken as $[-T,T]$ or any length of $2T$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help! I am still a little bit confused now how I should finish my prove: I defined a function $F(x) := \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(\frac T \pi x+ 2kT) $ to obtain a $2\pi$ periodic function, instead of a $2T$ periodic one. Calculating the fourier coefficients of this function gives me exactly the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. I would then move on to do substitution later to arrive at my result. I dont really know how I could immediately just integrate over $[-T,T]$. But the above sum of integrals over $[-\pi,\pi]$ is finite anyways?

Comment: If the function is the $F$, then the integral is taken on $[-\pi,\pi]$, you can use the reasoning provided by @reuns with some dilation.